# Source for Baal Haturim Writing Commentary on his Wedding Night!

Tags: sources-mekorot, commentaries, wedding

I've heard that the Baal Haturim wrote the whole commentary on the Chumash on his wedding night!

Can someone please provide the source for this?

Comment: I checked Shem Gedolim of the Chida didnt see any mention of this

Comment: Is this referring to his commentary known as "Baal HaTurim" or the one called "Tur Al HaTorah"/"Tur HeAroch"?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Hidabroot ([here](https://www.hidabroot.com/article/195657/7-Facts-About-Rabbi-Yaakov-Ben-Asher-on-The-Anniversary-of-His-Passing)) writes

> It is a well-known fact that Rabbi Yaakov [Ben Asher, the [Baal Haturim]](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jacob_ben_Asher) wrote his entire commentary
>   on the Torah in one night, orally, although no reliable source has
>   been found.

which is what you might have heard, although they don't connect it to his wedding night.

Thanks to @msh210, I found an official source in the introduction to Baal HaTurim's Torah commentary in the edition prepared by R Yaakov Koppel Reinitz, p. 9, where he writes that (as is mentioned in the *sefer* Kol Dodi), after his father commented that he was only busy with the Oral Torah, the Baal HaTurim took this to heart and wrote his commentary overnight !

[image]

Comment: Is this referring to his commentary known as "Baal HaTurim" or the one called "Tur Al HaTorah"/"Tur HeAroch"? Or comment st the end implies you understood it as referring to the former

Comment: @robev from the mention of *"parparot"* it is now clear this is the "short" commentary of *gematriot* since the Baal HaTurim saw it as an "appetizer" to his larger commentary

Comment: While I would guess that the story is still exaggerated (one night?!), he might have written the compilation quickly. Many of the gematrios are found in the Rokech and other works, and the rest of commentary is exerps from the Ramban.