# Baal HaTurim written for his father?

Tags: commentaries, tur

Rav Eytan Feiner [mentioned](https://www.torahanytime.com/#/lectures?v=116546) that the Baal Haturim wrote his commentary on Chumash in one night as a gift for his father. Although there [are](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/109564/13811) noting the commentary being written in one night, are there any sources saying this was written for his father? (And why?)

Comment: This is answered at https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/109564/170

Comment: Thank you for sharing that link - although I noted the same question within mine, it doesn't seem to say it was written as a gift for his father - am I mistaken?